# How to append an image into a table if the `if` statement matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if it's possible but below I have a simple html table:

```
<table id="plus" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the `if` statement matches, then is it possible to append the image inside the `<th>` tag above? And if the statement doesn't match then can I instead append the image link inside the `<th>` tag?

Below is the `if` statement, which is actually jQuery that includes a bit of php to try and find the 'textQuestion':

```
if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {
  <img src="Images/plussigndisabled.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
} else {
  <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
  <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
  </a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon for edit to make code look more presentable :)

Comment: Are you trying to insert this with jQuery or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you stated that you are using jQuery you can do this

```
....
    var enabledImage = "plussign.jpg";
    var disabledImage = "plussigndisabled.jpg";
    var selectedImage;
    var imageHtml;

    if(...) {
        selectedImage = enabledImage;
    } else {
        selectedImage = disabledImage;
    }  

    imageHtml = getImageHtml(selectedImage);
    $('#ElementID').append($(imageHtml));
....

function getImageHtml(imageFileName) {
    return '<img src="Images/' + imageFileName + '" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" name="plusbuttonrow"/>';
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the image source the variable, instead of duplicating the entire string? x = 'plussign.jpg', y = 'plussigndisabled.jpg'. Then append("<img src='" + x + "'"/ >")?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a unique ID to the TH as follows:

```
<table id="plus" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th id="foo">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then just use the inner HTML property.

```
var bar=document.getElementByID('foo');
bar.innerHtml="<img />";
```

(This assumes the javascript is run in response to user input, i. e. AFTER the page is finished loading)

Answer (score 0):

Either way you're going to be appending something, so determine *what* you're appending with the `if-statement`, and then append it. Either way, it's going in the same place.

```
$("#plus th").html(function(){
    return ( qnum === 5 )
        ? "<img />"
        : "<a><img /></a>" ;
});
```

At this point, append `data`.

Comment: So do I give `<th>` an id like imgappend and then state `(#imgappend).append(data);`?

Comment: @user1394925 You could, but it's not necessary. You could look it up with jQuery as I have above.

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/26Jaf/

Good API: http://api.jquery.com/append/

**code**

```
var qnum = 1;  
var append_data = "";
if (qnum == 1) { // i.e. if condition satisfy.

   append_data = '<img src="http://images.wikia.com/maditsmadfunny/images/5/54/Hulk-from-the-movie.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" name="plusbuttonrow"/>';


} else {
   //do something else

alert('d');
}
$("#plus tr th").append(append_data);
​
```